# How to remove tooltip from full screen mode watching youtube video in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, browser, google-chrome-devtools

After updating my Chrome browser, I see multiple updates. One of them is showing memory usage but it's coming on full-screen mode instead of hovering the tab.

Now, I'm getting one **tooltip** kind of thing on my browser while watching YouTube videos in full-screen mode. Also, It's hiding the website URL.

[image]

Any solution to remove/disable it?